# Create new geom/stat for ggplot and give warning on condition

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a new geom for ggplot2. e.g.,

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=foo, y=bar)) + geom_new()
```

in the code for geom_new (which will include both a newly defined `stat_new` and `geom_new`), I would like to add a condition e.g.,

```
if (foo >= 5) warning('foo should be less than 5')
```

Specifically, if that condition is triggered for a given observation, in addition to showing the warning message I need the geom_new for that observation to now be shown.

Essentially I need the observation to be treated like a missing value and just not shown.

Could someone provide an example (simple) stat and geom definition and show how this behavior can be achieved in their example?

Thank you!

Comment: Consider adding the work you've done so far to achieve this and where you got stuck.  Having an example dataset to use with the code would also be helpful.